# Consider width/height of parents when styling in Polymer

Tags: css, shadow-dom, polymer-2.x

I want to set the width of some elements within container elements in Polymer which is not working as I expected. Here's some small example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/webcomponents+:master/shadycss+webcomponents+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="my-container">
  <template>

    <paper-input label="Test"></paper-input>

  </template>

  <script>
      class MyContainer extends Polymer.Element {

          static get is() {
              return 'my-container';
          }

      }

      customElements.define(MyContainer.is, MyContainer);
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="my-element">

  <template>
    <style>
      #pblock {
        width: 50%;
      }
    </style>
    <my-container id="pblock"></my-container>
  </template>


  <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
          class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
              static get is() { return 'my-element'; }

          }
          customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
      });

  </script>

</dom-module>

<my-element></my-element>

</body>
</html>
```

I set the container to 50% width. Since the paper-input within that container is set to width 100%, I thought it considers 100% of its parent, i.e., 50% of the document.
However, the paper-input takes the whole width and does not react to the 50% of the container. How can I set the width (or height) of the container such that the internal element (in this case the paper-input) does use it as a percentual reference?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width: 50%;` is not reflecting because your `container` has `display: inline` change it to `display: block`

If you want it to be center aligned give `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/webcomponents+:master/shadycss+webcomponents+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="my-container">
  <template>

    <paper-input label="Test"></paper-input>

  </template>

  <script>
      class MyContainer extends Polymer.Element {

          static get is() {
              return 'my-container';
          }

      }

      customElements.define(MyContainer.is, MyContainer);
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="my-element">

  <template>
    <style>
      #pblock {
        width: 50%;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
    </style>
    <my-container id="pblock"></my-container>
  </template>


  <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
          class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
              static get is() { return 'my-element'; }

          }
          customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
      });

  </script>

</dom-module>

<my-element></my-element>

</body>
</html>
```